# Recursive makefile with two executables

Tags: c, makefile

I have a project which contains two main functions, one is for implementation of my program and the other main function is for testing the program. I searched the web for this but found almost nothing that was about recursive makefile with two executables.

**Makefile**

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

PROG = suggest

OBJDIR = objects
OBJS = $(OBJDIR)/suggest.o $(OBJDIR)/engine.o $(OBJDIR)/table.o $(OBJDIR)/levenshtein.o

# ... link them
$(PROG): $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)

$(OBJDIR)/table.o:
    $(MAKE) -C table.c
    cp ../file1/table.c/table.o $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/levenshtein.o:
    $(MAKE) -C levenshtein.c
    cp levenshtein.c/levenshtein.o $(OBJDIR)

# build them all...
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR) $(PROG)
```

In the above file, `engine.c` is a main function that does the implementation of my program however i have another `main` function as well, called `test.c` that does testing on my file.
What i want is, when i run the `make` command, it should only build the `engine.c` `main` function (by default) but if i want to test my program i should be able to run the `test.c` `main` function by specifying something like this, for instance `make test`.

---

The problem is i don't have a makefile for test file. My directory is like this: engine.c , suggest.c , test.c and then i have another folder called levenshtein.c and that has got its own makefile. Also i just want to work with only two makefiles. I have already written one which is in the levenshtein.c folder and the one that i have problem is this one as this folder contains two `main` functions.I would want a conditional compilation based on the command.

Comment: makefiles usually only build (compile) your code. Are you sure you really want to  "execute the `engine.c` `main` function" when you run the `make` command? Or does "execute" mean "build" in this context?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the recursive keyword. I don't see anything recursive here. On the other matter, you can just specify `test:` and add the logic in there(you have `clean` as example).

Comment: My bad, Well i meant build my files, not execute. @anatolyg

Comment: The `levenshtein.c` has got its own makefile and it is in a different directory. So this makefile will recursively execute the makefile of `levenshtein.c` directory. Same goes for `table.c`. @IvRRimUm

Comment: @IvRRimUm: The lines in the makefile that start with `$(MAKE)` are recursive invocations of Make, which makes this a recursive makefile.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Opps, sorry, my bad.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it would be adding a dedicated makefile for your testing feature. You could add stuff to your existing makefile, but it would go against your existing methodology, where you have a makefile for each small feature. BTW you can [edit] your post to add any clarifications you think are necessary.

Comment: Just edited my post for clarification. Also you're correct that i should have a mini makefile for testing but since my i can't have more than one makefile per folder, i'd want this makefile to have some kind of conditional statement that runs a specific `main` function. @anatolyg

Comment: I see a few errors in this Makefile.  Honestly, recursive make is a bit tricky to get right, and it's easy to make it so some targets get rebuild when they don't need it, or other targets don't get rebuild when they do need it.  For example, none of the `.o` files in this makefile will get rebuilt correctly.  My suggestion is to avoid splitting executables across multiple makefiles—just put rules for all of the `.o` files and the executable in the same makefile.  The problem is that Make can't really evaluate dependencies across recursive calls.  Alternatively, use a different build system.

Comment: Let me advertise my non-recursive build system which can help achieve that easily, it is called `prorab`. I have also put together a simple example, can be found here https://github.com/igagis/prorab/tree/master/examples/app_and_test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the above answers were very helpful but i still wasn't able to run my program. After getting some hints from the above answers, i was able to come up with a simplified version of makefile. The above ones are also accurate depending on the setup of your directories. This is how i did it.

*(NOTE: this may not be the best solution)*

```
TEST = test.c engine.c levenshtein.c/levenshtein.c ../subdir1/table.c
PROG = suggest.c engine.c levenshtein.c/levenshtein.c ../subdir1/table.c
OBJ_TEST = $(TEST:.c=.o)
OBJ_PROG = $(PROG:.c=.o)

CC = clang
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

test: $(OBJ_TEST)
    $(CC) $(OBJ_TEST) -o $@

suggest: $(OBJ_PROG)
    $(CC) $(OBJ_PROG) -o $@

.SUFFIXES: .c .o
.c.o:
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

I had a parent directory which contained two more folders. My directory set-up looked like this:

> Project/
>
> |_____ subdirectory that contained table.c
>
> |_____ another subdirectory that contained my engine.c, suggest.c and test.c, and it contained levenshtein.c as well which was a separate folder.

So for any future readers if you are reading this, take note of your directories and then try to create a makefile as it will make life less stressful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;  Adding the new target TEST and conditionally linking in either engine.o or test.o.  This will only work if your test program doesn't require any of the functions or data in engine.o  If it does you may want to conditionally compile the two main functions using something like -DTEST_PROGRAM

Since you're using other functions and data from engine.o you should add something like #if USE_TEST_PROGRAM #endif around the main(...) function inside of engine.c and define the USE_TEST_PROGRAM flag in your makefile as shown below.  This will have the side effect of compiling engine.c twice (once into your OBJDIR for your program suggest and once in your top dir for your test program).

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

PROG = suggest
TEST = test

OBJDIR = objects
OBJS = $(OBJDIR)/suggest.o $(OBJDIR)/table.o $(OBJDIR)/levenshtein.o

# ... link them
$(PROG): $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)/engine.o -o $(PROG)

$(TEST): $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DUSE_TEST_PROGRAM=1 engine.c $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)/test.o -o $(PROG)

$(OBJDIR)/table.o:
    $(MAKE) -C table.c
    cp ../file1/table.c/table.o $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/levenshtein.o:
    $(MAKE) -C levenshtein.c
    cp levenshtein.c/levenshtein.o $(OBJDIR)

# build them all...
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR) $(PROG)
```

Comment: Code without explanations is not helpful. If the code doesn't work well, you need explanations to improve it.

Comment: @anatolyg Is this enough explanation?

Comment: I am using functions from engine.o, can you please explain the second part which is about conditional compilation?

Comment: @Saad have you seen my edits?  Please accept the answer if it's helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use recursion for what you're doing.

By the sounds of your description you want to have a single makefile, which builds one of two final targets: either `test` or `engine`.   For `test`, it should compile and link `test.c`.   For `engine`, it should compile and link `engine.c`.

If this is correct, you could build a makefile with two targets as so:

```
test engine: $(PROG)

.PHONY: test engine
```

So each target depnds on `$(PROG)`.  You then modify your makefile to have the correct list of objects to build:

```
OBJS := ....

ifneq ($(filter test,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
    #test was a command goal, add test.o to the targets:
    OBJS+=$(OBJDIR)/test.o
else ifneq ($(filter engine,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
    #engine was a command goal, add test.o to the targets:
    OBJS+=$(OBJDIR)/engine.o
else
    #neither were command goals.  set default:
    OBJS+=$(OBJDIR)/engine.o
fi

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
     @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $? -o $@
```

now when you run `make test`, it will add test.o to `$(OBJS)`, build and link (`$?` will contain all .o files), otherwise it will add `engine.o` to `$(OBJS)`.   Make will compile all the $(OBJS) and build your target.

One other thing.  You have:

```
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
```

(which is good, but not so good, you have:

```
$(PROG): $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)
```

First of all, it will try to build the objects before it creates the object directory (which can cause a build failure).  Also, if `objdir` is made ahead of time, and the compilation works, the timestamp on `$(OBJDIR)` is updated each time a file inside that directory changes...  So it it would likely be newer than `$(PROG)`, causing it to be rebuilt often when it doesn't need to be.   The correct way to do this is:

```
$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)
```

notice the `|`, which means order-only dependency, meaning it won't rebuild `$(OBJS)` if `$(OBJDIR)` has a newer timestamp, but it will build the directory before any of the objects.